# How to use createConnection of mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose as below.

```
// .env
   MONGO_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/users
```

And mongoDB runs on app.js.

```
// app.js

const connect = () => mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, dbOptions, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('db error, connect in 5sec');
  }
  return app.listen(4000, () => console.log('App bounded'));
});
connect();
```

And there is an api as below.

```
   // api.js

   const user = require('./models/userSchema')

   router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
       const result =  await user.find({name: 'test'})
       res.send(result)
   }
```

But now I want to make one server using diverse collenction in it.
So I have to change the env file.

```
// .env
    MONGO_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
```

And there are many collections in Mongodb like 'users', 'testers' etc.
And Api works like..

```
  // api.js

   const user = require('./models/userSchema')
   const testers = require('./models/testerSchema')

   router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
       const result =  await user.find({name: 'test'})
       const result2 = await testers.find({name: 'test2'})
       res.send(result, result2)
   }
```

I found 'createConnection' But I don't know where I should put this and how to read each database and collections in my arquitecture. Could you recommend some solutions?
Thank you so much for reading it.

Comment: Do you want multiple connection in mongodb?

Comment: your understanding in not correct, the name you pass in the connection string is the name of **database** you wanna use, and collections exists inside databases. Once you connect to a specific database, you can access any of its collection using the models. The name of the collection needs to be define while creating the model.

Comment: @d337 yes, I want to use multiple connection in mongodb. But I dont want to make multiple server for each conection. I just want to share databases in one server.

Comment: @Mohammed Amir Ansari How can I access multiple database in one server using my node service directory like app.js, api.js and.env?

Comment: @DDDD : I did get this `But now I want to make one server using diverse collenction in it.` Do you wanted to connect to another DB (mongoDB hosted in different mongo cluster ? Or another db hosted in same mongo cluster ?) Also why does your mongo url is like this :: `MONGO_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/users`, Is `users` is db name ?